# Localization in ASP.Net core MVC not working - unable to locate resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, globalization

In trying to localize my application, I've followed the steps here:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/localization.html

Here is my code:

**Startup.cs**

```
public List<IRequestCultureProvider> RequestCultureProviders { get; private set; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddViewLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

    services.AddOptions();

    services.AddTransient<IViewRenderingService, ViewRenderingService>();

    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
    app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())),
        EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
    });

    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("fr"),
    };

    app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("fr"),
        // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
        SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
        // UI strings that we have localized.
        SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures,
        RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
        {
           new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider
           {
               QueryStringKey = "culture",
               UIQueryStringKey = "ui-culture"
           }
        }
    });


}
```

**MyController.cs**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IViewRenderingService _viewRenderingService;
    private IStringLocalizer<MyController> _localizer;
    private MyOptions _options;
    //Constructor for dependency injection principle
    public MyController(IViewRenderingService viewRenderingService, IStringLocalizer<MyController> localizer, IOptions<MyOptions> options)
    {
        _viewRenderingService = viewRenderingService;
        _localizer = localizer;
        _options = options.Value;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        // _localizer["Name"] 
        return _localizer["Product"];
    }
}
```

The `*.resx` file is stored in the `Resources` folder, with the name `Controllers.MyController.fr.resx` (which has an entry for "Product").

However, it's not able to find the resource file, and "Product" is never returned in French. I am using querystring, so here is the query string:

```
localhost:3333/my?culture=fr
```

Also in the View, `@Localizer["Product"]` returns "Product".

Can anyone please help me find whats missing?

**EDIT:**

After some investigation, I found that culture is getting changed, however it is unable to locate the Resource file. I am using VS2015. can anyone help?

Comment: The culture string for France is `fr-FR`

Comment: @JK. Still same result and if you check the link I have provided, they have also used only "fr" culture.

Answer (score 29):

I had similar problem. Than I figured out that the 
"**Localization.AspNetCore.TagHelpers**" nuget packag was missing from my project.
It's look like it is a required package for the QueryStringRequestCultureProvider.

Comment: Just as an FYI, you do realize that the package `Localization.AspNetCore.TagHelprs` does **not** come from Microsoft, right? Of course it's not documented, it's not official.

Comment: This package is not compatible with .NET Core 2.

Comment: For me it was the NuGet package `Microsoft.Extensions.Localization`.

Comment: In my case, I installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization` which did the trick. I'm using Core 2.2

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem in .net core 2.2
i see in the debugger the properties SearchedLocation
[image]

so, i created first the files Controllers.HomesController.rsx without language extension with access modifier "Public" to accces to the property
[image]

and with localizer["Property] i found the goood value.

After i created the Controllers.HomeController.fr.resx and he found the good value with culture in url.

Answer (score 5):

If the root namespace of an assembly is different than the assembly name:

Localization does not work by default.
Localization fails due to the way resources are searched for within the assembly. RootNamespace is a build-time value which is not available to the executing process.

If the RootNamespace is different from the AssemblyName, include the following in AssemblyInfo.cs (with parameter values replaced with the actual values):

```
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;

[assembly: ResourceLocation("Resource Folder Name")]
[assembly: RootNamespace("App Root Namespace")]
```

[More info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2#resource-file-naming)

Comment: To help you identify the reason the values aren't resolving, you can inject IStringLocalizerFactory and look at the _localizerCache non-public member.  You can see what resource it is trying to load.

Comment: this was definitely my problem. I would love to share a suggestion, "don't use hypens (-) in your project name, because they are keep as is in the Assembly but changed to underscore (_) in the namespace"!!

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by setting the build action of the resx resource file to "embedded resource" 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the problem was that I was specifying:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

and:

```cs
options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) => 
    factory.Create(typeof(DataAnnotations));
```

where my DataAnnotations.resx resource file was also located under the "Resources" namespace. This was causing the localizer to search for strings in "MyApp.Resources.Resources.DataAnnotations" instead of "MyApp.Resources.DataAnnotations".

Changing the first line to:

```
services.AddLocalization();
```

helped solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Visual studio IDE resolves the assembly references, but it requires the Microsoft.Extensions.Localization and Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions NuGets. Once I added them to the project reference, the resource locator is able to find the resource files!

Answer (score 3):

I spent an hour trying to figure out the same and it turned out (in my case) I had not set the access modifier of my resource file to `public`. Worked fine once it made it public.
[image]

Probably worth a shot to re-check it to make sure you don't end up debugging for an hour for nothing ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add these references from `nuget`:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
```

and also `Localization.AspNetCore.TagHelpers` can be a good tag helper instead of injecting the localization stuffs every time to the views

Answer (score 2):

For me it was a problem that the name of the project's folder was different than the root namespace! Core 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

I am using VS 2017 targeting .NET Core 2.1 and in my case the project file (.csproj) contained a few strange ItemGroup tags, like these:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Resources\Controllers.HomeController.sv.resx" />
    ...
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Resources\Controllers.HomeController.sv.resx" />
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

When I deleted the lines it started working.

I had been experimenting earlier with adding and removing the resource files so that might have caused the item groups to appear, but it's strange that Visual Studio inserted these lines at all. Seems like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was actually missing the explicit setting of the `ResourcesPath`:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by removing the built-in providers in order to be able to use the default request culture.
For do that you'll need to add this code to your services.Configure in the startup class:

```
    options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
    {
        new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
        new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
    };
```

Please take a look to this other answer:
[ASP .NET Core default language is always English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480759/asp-net-core-default-language-is-always-english/44496575#44496575)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add "Localization.AspNetCore.TagHelpers" NuGet package in your project by using the following command

```
Install-Package Localization.AspNetCore.TagHelpers -Version 0.6.0
```

I hope it will fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

For me it was "-" in project name - it got changed for "_" and localization couldn't find files

Answer (score -2):

My solution to this problem was to rename the generated resource code namespace from for example:

from

namespace ProjectName.Resources
to
namespace ProjectName

It works for me.