# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Translations always in English

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I'm currently developing a multilanguage ASP.NET Core 2.0-website.
I read the [official documantion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization) and investigated the [example](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Localization.StarterWeb) provided on GitHub.

Below is the folder structure of the project:

[image]

Grabbed code from my Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Translations");

        services.AddMvc()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix, options => options.ResourcesPath = "Translations")
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

        // Configure supported cultures and localization options
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("nl"),
                //new CultureInfo("en")
            };

            // State what the default culture for your application is. This will be used if no specific culture
            // can be determined for a given request.
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "nl", uiCulture: "nl");

            // You must explicitly state which cultures your application supports.
            // These are the cultures the app supports for formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;

            // These are the cultures the app supports for UI strings, i.e. we have localized resources for.
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //use the configured localization options for each request.
        var localizationOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions.Value);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }


        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

In my view (for example `Home/Index`) I call the Localizer: `<h1>@Localizer["Welcome"]</h1>`. The key `Welcome` exists in the `Index.nl.resx`-file, but unfortunatelt it's never translated to dutch.

I tried to explicitly change the culture by calling the url with `?culture=nl` and changed my browser language to Dutch, but none of both did the job.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**
Below my `Home/Index.cshtml` file:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<h1>@Localizer["Welcome"]</h1>
```

Injection is done in the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
```

Comment: Can you show your view? Did you inject @inject IViewLocalizer Localizer and is the resource file available?

Comment: I added my view. As you can see it is quiet simple. The resource file is located under `Translations/Views/Home/Index.nl.resx` as you can see in the screenshot from the solution explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the technique described by tmg in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44496575/1626109).

This means that you should add the following code to your `ConfigureServices()` function:

```
CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = new[]
{
    new CultureInfo("en"),
    new CultureInfo("nl")
};

services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.DefaultRequestCulture   = new RequestCulture("nl");
    options.SupportedCultures       = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures     = supportedCultures;
    options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
    {
        new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
        new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
    };
});
```

and replace your call to `app.UseRequsestLocalization` in the `Configure()` function with a simple call without parameters:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization();
```