# ASP.Net MVC Core refuses to set current culture correctly for views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-localization

Please help me because I'm losing my mind here :-(

I'm trying to figure out how `ASP.Net MVC Core Localization` works. I worked according to MS's tutorial but to no avail.

Long story short: I'm configuring `RequestLocalizationOptions` to default to Hebrew (`he-IL`). I have appropriate resource files in a directory structure based on my views (and I know that works because changing resources in the default `en-US` resource file DOES reflect in the UI).

When I run my application, my view are localized to English, not Hebrew.

Bonus oddity: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` IS indeed set to `he-IL` when I break inside the Startup.cs code, but it is then set back to `en-US` for all other threads, which I verify in the view by printing `<H2>@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name</H2>`. I tried setting both `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` inside my controller actions, but that doesn't work.

Basically:

```
    // Startup.cs
    private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // localization
        services
            .AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var hebrew = new CultureInfo("he-IL");
            var usEnglish = new CultureInfo("en-US");

            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                hebrew, usEnglish
            };

            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(hebrew, hebrew);
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });

        // MVC
        services.AddMvc((options) => { options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()); })
            .AddViewLocalization()
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

        // other configurations go here...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // localization
        var localizationOption = app
            .ApplicationServices
            .GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOption.Value);

        // other configurations go here...
    }
```

Then, in any view:

```
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
    @using System.Threading

    @inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

    <H1>@Localizer["Test string"]</H1>
    <H2>@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name</H2>
```

The result I'm getting:

```
<H1>Test string</H1>
<H2>en-US</H2>
```

should be:

```
<H1>טקסט בעברית</H1>
<H2>he-IL</H2>
```

Comment: What happens if you try adding the quesry string - ?culture=he-IL&ui-culture=he-IL

Comment: @bsod_  - when I add this query string I get the correct result... but I need to set the culture grammatically inside the application! How do I do that? Why doesn't Microsoft's code (above) work?

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480759/asp-net-core-default-language-is-always-english)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP .NET Core default language is always English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480759/asp-net-core-default-language-is-always-english)

Comment: In my case it was due to the fact that I used e.g. "`de-DE`" or "`en-US`" instead of e.g. "`de`" or "`en`" for the supported cultures and RequestCulture. After the change to e.g. "`de`" or "`en`", the system worked perfectly, even if my browser sent e.g. a "`de-DE`", it was correctly matched with the server-side provided "`de`" culture/language.