# Localization not picking specific resource culture file for validation messsages in .net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have added code for validation messages in .net core. Each time default file is loading for messages.

I have added resource files as below
1. Resource.resx
2.Resource.de.resx

[image]

Every time messages are loaded from 1st default file, by default I have set culture to 'DE'.

```
ViewModel 
   [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "the_first_name_field_is_required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(OneView.Library.Resources.Resource))]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "the_last_name_field_is_required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(OneView.Library.Resources.Resource))]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

**************************************************************************
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {   services.AddLocalization(o =>
            {
                o.ResourcesPath = "Resources";
            });

            services.AddMvc()
                        .AddViewLocalization(
            LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
            opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })

        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
       services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
        opts =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("EN-US"),
                new CultureInfo("de"),
            };

            opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("de");
            //// Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            // UI strings that we have localized.
            opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
  }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting "de" as `DefaultRequestCulture` but `DefaultRequestCulture` is used if none of the built-in providers can determine the request culture.From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#localization-middleware), the default providers are:

- QueryStringRequestCultureProvider
- CookieRequestCultureProvider
- AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider

You could overwrite the `RequestCultureProviders` list of `RequestLocalizationOptions` and use only the other two providers. In `Startup.cs`:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
        opts =>
        {
        var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
        {
            new CultureInfo("EN-US"),
            new CultureInfo("de"),
        };

        opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("de");
        //// Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
        opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        // UI strings that we have localized.
        opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        opts.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
        {
            new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
            new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
        };
       });
 }
```

Reference: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44496575/10201850