# Change Default language in ASP .Net Core Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I developed a ASP .Net Core project and when I published to IIS, the calendar menu and the formatting string like : `.ToString("D dddd-MM-yyyy")` are in English. I want to set the default language to **Italian**, I want the calendar menu and DateTime string (month/day) to be in Italian.

Searching on internet I found this : [ASP .NET Core default language is always English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480759/asp-net-core-default-language-is-always-english)
And I do this in `Startup()`:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
        
      CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = new[]
      {
         new CultureInfo("it-IT")
         //new CultureInfo("en")
      };

      services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
      {
          options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("it-IT");
          options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
          options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
          options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
          {
             new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
             new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
          };
         });
      ...
     }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
      ...
      app.UseRequestLocalization(); 

      app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseSession();

        //app.UseMvc();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{area=Admin}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

    }
```

Also I changed HTML `lang` to `it` in every page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing everything correctly, in any case this didn't work for me.

Any suggestions/examples to set Italian or whatever language to default language?

Comment: I don’t know if the _calendar menu_ you mentioned is similar to `@Localizer["key"]`. If not, it is because the language of the client is determined by the browser. You can set it in the browser (chrome): setting->advanced->Language.

Comment: That's worked. But can I do it by code? What if this project is going to use Italian that leaves in China and have chrome in chinese

Comment: JavaScript cannot change default language. It can only get. You can try vba.

Answer (score 0):

in web config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization
            culture="it-IT"
            uiCulture="it-IT"
        />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```